# Swift UILabel subclass automatically call enum switch function

Tags: ios, swift, class, enums, uilabel

I have been creating a UILabel class called RPLabel, which is supposed to shorten all of my long list of programmatically set labels. This is the class code:

```
class RPLabel: UILabel {

    //    moneyTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: -50, width:XX, height: 35)  //

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setup()
        self.testForLabelType()

    }

    enum labelTypeEnumeration {
        case title, subtitle
    }

    var labelType = labelTypeEnumeration.title

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()



    }



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()

    }

    func setup(){
        self.text = self.text
        self.textColor = self.textColor
        self.font = self.font
        self.layer.display()
    }



    func testForLabelType() {

        switch labelType {
        case .title:
            setupTitle()
            print("setupTitle")
        case .subtitle:
            setupSubtitle()
            print("setupSubtitle")
        }

    }

    func setupTitle(){
        self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        self.textColor = UIColor.secondaryColor()
        self.textAlignment = .left

    }

    func setupSubtitle(){
        self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        self.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 200, green: 200, blue: 200)
        self.textAlignment = .left

    }



}
```

To make a label, I use the following piece of code:

```
var moneyTitle = RPLabel()
    moneyTitle.labelType = .title
    moneyTitle.testForLabelType()
    moneyTitle.text = "MONEY"
    moneyTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: -50, width:XX, height: 35)
```

The issue that I have is that I would like to set the labelType to .title without having to write moneyTitle.testForLabelType(). In other words, I would like for that function to run automatically in the class. An alternative I would not like would be inserting the parameter in the init, so please avoid telling me to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use didSet:

> didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.

```
var labelType = labelTypeEnumeration.title {
    didSet {
        testForLabelType()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if you question were answered successfully =).